# Find pattern in pandas column names and change such columns using pipe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pipe

Let say I have below calculation,

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame({'xx1' : [1,2,3], 'aa2' : ['qq', '4', 'd'], 'xx3' : [4,5,6]})
dat2 = (dat
        .assign(xx1 = lambda x : [str(i) for i in x['xx1'].values])
        .assign(xx3 = lambda x : [str(i) for i in x['xx3'].values])
    )
```

Basically, I need to find those columns for which column names match pattern `xx + sequence of numbers` (i.e. `xx1, xx2, xx3` etc) and then apply some transformation to those column (e.g. apply `str` function)

One way I can do this is like above i.e. find manually those columns and perform transformation. I wonder if there is any way to generalise this approach. I prefer to use `pipe` like above.

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Comment: Did you mean to write `xx2` as column name instead of `aa2`?

Comment: No. I need to find the column names with pattern `xx + numbers` then apply transformation only to those columns

Comment: I see, and the transformation is the same for all the columns? Or dependent on the actual column name?

Comment: Yes, the applied transformation will be same for all shortlisted columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
# Matches all columns starting with 'xx' with a sequence of numbers afterwards. 
cols_to_transform = dat.columns[dat.columns.str.match('^xx[0-9]+$')]

# Transform to apply (column-wise).
transform_function = lambda c: c.astype(str)

# If you want a new DataFrame and not modify the other in-place.
dat2 = dat.copy()

dat2[cols_to_transform] = dat2[cols_to_transform].transform(transform_function, axis=0)
```

To use it within `assign`:

```
# Here I put a lambda to avoid precomputing all the transformations in the dict comprehension.
dat.assign(**{col: lambda df: df[col].astype(str) for col in cols_to_transform})
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I use this with continuation of my original `.assign` method?

Comment: @BrianSmith check my edit

Comment: That is excellent. However when I use this like `(dat
  .assign(xx1 = lambda x : [str(i) for i in x['xx1'].values])
  .assign(xx2 = lambda x : [str(i) for i in x['xx2'].values])
  .assign(**{col: dat[col].astype(str) for col in cols_to_transform})
 )` it fails. Is there any way to perform the same in this way?

Comment: @BrianSmith what error do you get? I tried myself just now and it works. EDIT: maybe it's because you still have `'xx2'` instead of `'xx3'` in the second `assign`?

Comment: Sorry! Its my mistake as I wrongly using `X2` in the place of `X3`. Many thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
frame = pd.DataFrame({'xx1' : [1,2,3], 'aa2' : ['qq', '4', 'd'], 'xx3' : [4,5,6]})

def parse_column(col, vals):
    if "xx" == col[:2] and col[2:].isdigit():
        return [str(i) for i in vals]
    return vals

for (name, col) in frame.iteritems():
    frame[name] = parse_column(name, col.values)
```

1. you can iterate over columns, getting their names and values as a series
2. the incredibly niche `str.isdigits()` function exists as an inherent part of python for some reason, but it came in useful here

Answer (score 0):

One option is to select the relevant columns, apply your function and assign them back to the dataframe via unpacking:

```py
result = dat.assign(**dat.filter(regex=r"xx\d+").astype(str))

result.dtypes

xx1    object
aa2    object
xx3    object
dtype: object

dat.dtypes

xx1     int64
aa2    object
xx3     int64
dtype: object
```